# Spring/MongoDB Probleme with MongoOperation.updateMulti that update only one field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

In my Activity document I want to update a collection of actions status which ids are in a list :

```js
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "actions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "status" : "todo"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "status" : "in progress"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "status" : "done"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "status" : "done"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "status" : "todo"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to write a code using MongoOperation.updateMulti but it updates only one status at all :

```java
mongoOperation.updateMulti(
    new Query().addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("_id").is(activityId).and("actionsActivite._id").in(actionsIds)),
    new Update().set("actionsActivite.$.status", newStatut),
    ActivityModel.class
);
```

I don't know where the problem is. Is my Query wrong ? My Update ?

Comment: First you're using "actionsActivite" in your query but in you table it looks like you have "actions", is it an alias ? 
Secondly, to me it seems normal, that you only udpate one field since, your condition is on the id of the global object and then the _id of a field, but the _id a UNIQUE field right ? So your query, find a result and then updates the status field as you're asking

Comment: The id of action if unique for one activity but you could have many activities with the same action. So how could I write my condition please ?

Comment: Well, if I understand you database collection correctly, you just need to remove your first where condition...
Because you want to look for action which have the value "actionIds" in each activity right ?
So  "actionsActivite._id").is(actionsIds)"  should be the only condition ?

Comment: Not in each activity, only for the activity with the id "activityId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I just add $[] operator in the update like this :

```java
mongoOperation.updateMulti(
    new Query().addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("_id").is(activityId).and("actionsActivite._id").in(actionsIds)),
    new Update().set("actionsActivite.$[].status", newStatut),
    ActivityModel.class
);
```